# Where does the use of "deck" to mean "set of slides" come from?

Tags: etymology

Nowadays, the word *deck* can be used to refer to a set of slides (e.g., PowerPoint slides). Where does that sense come from? [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/deck)  didn't yield any insight on it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123999/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-where-does-the-use-of-deck-to-mea).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A couple of slide decks:

[image]

A card deck:

[image]

Comment: This reminds me of one of those single-diagram math papers. Very succinct and elegant answer!

Comment: So now I wonder, why are those items called decks? Neither of them looks like the floor of a ship.. :)

Comment: Although the term itself might come from projector slides, I don't think that explains the recent spike in usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slide+deck&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslide%20deck%3B%2Cc0

It also has a strong association with the corporate world; I've never heard it used in academia where there are slides presentations all the time.

Comment: @CaiusJard Perhaps not a ship with 1 or 2 decks, but I could see some similarity to a many-decked ship. If the planks are parallel to the decking (as is typical), the side view looks reminiscent as well. I have no idea if this is actually the answer, though.

Comment: @CaiusJard https://www.etymonline.com/word/deck "extended early in English from "covering" to "platform of a ship." Meaning "pack of cards necessary to play a game" is from 1590s, perhaps because they were stacked like decks of a ship." Might be a good question for the site on the history of the term Deck of Cards...

Comment: In High School we used to refer to the transparent plastic sheets for presentations with overhead projectors as 'slides'. I wonder if this was due to their similarity to 35mm slides

Comment: @KevinHooke - There was no such thing when I was in high school.  Somewhere around 1972 folks started talking about "foils", though by then true foils had gone away and they were really using what came to be called "overhead transparencies".  After that various terms were used, but the term "slides" was still reserved for the square things in cardboard until much later.

Comment: @WernerCD Like the deck of a ship, or like multiple floors in a building - surely multi-story buildings long predated multi-deck ships.  Which begs the question of why the floors on a ship are called "decks" in the first place when "floor" was already a perfectly good word for that.  But then naval lingo has different words for everything for some reason.

Comment: This sense of *deck of cards* is still common in the US, but  in the UK mostly replaced by *pack of cards*... does the usage *deck of slides* persist in the UK?

Comment: @GEdgar To me (AmE), a *pack of cards* refers to cards still in their original box.  Once they've been removed from the box, it's a deck until you put them back in the box.

Comment: @emily I wonder if the recent spike is related to Hypercard somehow--I think that program referred to them as decks but I could be wrong.

Comment: @CaiusJard, the Army says "hit the deck" regardless of whether they are on a ship or not. And usually it's not. Common use of "deck" to mean "floor" means that common use of a word for something other than it's single, intended use is, well, common. :-)

Answer (score 18):

The definition as a deck of cards is older (1593 Shakespeare King Henry IV is the earliest citation found):

> Alas, that Warwicke had no more fore‑cast,
> But whiles he thought to steale the single Ten,
> The King was slyly finger'd from the Deck:
> You left poore Henry at the Bishops Pallace,
> And tenne to one you'le meet him in the Tower.

..than the more general definition as "a pile of things laid flat upon each other" (1625) (image from the OED):

[image]

Incidentally, we referred to stacks of computer punch cards (Hollerith cards) as "decks" in the 1970s.

Like many other terms, "deck" was extended to apply to virtual stacks.

In the nautical sense (as a covering) it's older again and thought to come from Flemish or Low German. In modern Dutch "dekbed" is a bed covering (a duvet).

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the term was derived from the expression “a deck of playing cards” as suggested in the following extract:

> ***[A slide deck](https://slidebean.com/blog/startups-what-is-a-slide-deck)*** is just another way to refer to a presentation deck or pitch deck. The term was perhaps first used in Silicon Valley.

> As a little bit of history and to clarify on the above, the term slide deck comes from old technology. It goes back to times when we used those old slide projectors facing a wall. For those machines to work, the slides piled up as cards, just like a deck of cards.
>
> (slidebean.com)

Comment: That web writer does not look like an authority to me....

Comment: @Lambie - I think the idea suggested in the post is quite plausible, see also the answer below.

Comment: There were decks of slides before "Silicon Valley" existed.

Comment: 1966 is the earliest reference I've found via Google Books and Hathitrust, in this document - https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Junior_College_Library/IK4XAAAAIAAJ

Comment: But now I need to ask why a set of playing cards is called a deck :-)

Comment: @jamesqf : see here https://www.etymonline.com/word/deck

Comment: @PhilMJones This patent (US 3217436) https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ee/24/0b/e85c94ddbbb559/US3217436.pdf is somewhat older.  Filed in 1962, issued in 1965.  See starting at column 3, line 40, used the term a few times.

Answer (score 8):

Been doing powerpoints for years as an analyst. First time I ever heard them called "slide decks" was when I started hanging out with marketers. Then in college (went back to college in my late 30's to get bach/masters), I took grad-level marketing analytics classes. Again, prof called them "slide decks". No other professor or class called them "decks".

So, my idea is that marketers used to show up to presentations with posterboard decks they'd put on easels to do a presentation. They'd have an art dept put together their "deck", and they'd cycle through it as they did the presentation.

Then powerpoint came along, and they could do these decks in ppt as a slide show instead.

Marketing & Sales depts tends to be the hip, buzzword generators of the corporate world, constantly finding new, cool lingo to use to sell folks on ideas. So, my feeling is that marketers used the term "slide deck" enough to refer to powerpoint presentations that other dept's adopted the saying.

Back out in the working world, I noticed "slide deck" is used more often now. College profs usually head into college and isolate from the working world, so they dont' keep up with lingo. So, only marketer types are hip to the "slide deck" trend, b/c they're the ones that started using it in the first place.

This is my completely subjective opinion based on my limited personal experience extrapolated out into broad generalization. So, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: This corresponds to my experience also. This came from marketeers, is my guess. Why? Who knows? The marketing mind is another species, possibly of extraterrestrial birth -- certainly not *homo sapiens*.

Comment: Back in the days before presentation software (powerpoint) with video projectors, presenters and their secretaries would print (or manually create) information on 8-1/2x11 transparency "paper". Often for durability they would be mounted on a cardboardish frame. Thus you'd have a "deck" of slides. Which would then be shown on an "overhead projector".

Comment: @Firstrock The thing is that the users of OHPs called their acetate (or plastic) sheets "slides" because they fulfilled the same function as photographic "slides" which really did slide across the projector beam when changed. The term is really old having come in with the nineteenth century "magic lanterns". Some of those slides were photographic, some hand painted and a few even had moving parts.

Comment: TIL the origin of PowerPoint, lol