# What's the etymology of 'Deck' with a pack of cards?

Tags: etymology

The word deck has several meanings, most of which seem to have some logic behind them. I am stuggling to find any sensible reference to deck being the word to mean a set of cards.

[An earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562839/where-does-the-use-of-deck-to-mean-set-of-slides-come-from)/answers makes reference to a 'deck of slides', but I reckon a pack of cards existed well before slides.

Any logical reason why 'deck' has become the word for a pack of playing cards - on both sides of the Atlantic?

Comment: I think of 'deck of cards' as definitely American (and so do Oxford Dictionaries).

Comment: *OED* says "Since 17th cent. *dialect* and in *U.S.*", but has examples from England before that.

Comment: @KateBunting - my dictionaries support that. However, I'm certain I've heard it used in U.K.

Comment: The answer is found in the etymonline link posted in the slightly older question. *Sense extended early in English from "covering" to **"platform of a ship."** Meaning "pack of cards necessary to play a game" is from 1590s, [perhaps because they were stacked like decks of a ship](https://www.etymonline.com/word/deck). Tape-deck (1949) is in reference to the flat surface of old reel-to-reel tape recorders*.

Answer (score 1):

OED:

> **Deck n.**
>
> **Etymology:** In sense 1, apparently of Flemish or Low German origin.
> In sense 1, probably < Middle Dutch dec (neuter) roof, covering, cloak, pretext (apparently < decke < Old Germanic þakjom , from same root as deck v.)
>
> But in the nautical sense, 2, the word is not known in Dutch before 1675–81, when dek (neuter) appears as a synonym of verdek *[edit Greybeard = covering]*:, Thus, deck in the nautical sense, appears to be known in English 160 years earlier than in Dutch. It may be simply a specific application of the general sense ‘covering’, or it may come more immediately from the Middle Dutch sense ‘roof.’
>
> **I. A covering, platform, or surface.**
>
> **†1. A covering. Obsolete.In quot. 1466   apparently some material used for covering; with 1712 cf. Dutch dek ‘horse-cloth’.**
>
> 1466   in Manners & Househ. Expenses Eng. (1841) 348   My mastyr paid to John Felawe, for xij. yerdes of dekke for the spynas, iijs.

This gave rise to:

> **2.a.** *Nautical.* **A platform extending from side to side of a ship or part of a ship, covering in the space below, and also itself serving as a floor; […]. The primary notion was ‘covering’ or ‘roof’ rather than ‘floor’: see the quote [...] 1466 at sense 1, where the ‘dekke for the spynas’ or pinnace, may have been a covering of canvas, tarpaulin, or the like.**
>
> 1513   E. Echyngham Let. to Wolsey in A. Spont Lett. & Papers War France (1897) X. 152   *And bycause I hade no rayles upon my dek I coyled a cable rounde a[long] dek, brest hye, and likwise in the waste.*

The above seem to have been the earliest meaning (compare verbs to deck and to bedeck - to decorate by covering with items) but within a short time, we have our deck of cards

> **II. A pack or pile of things, and related uses.**
>
> **5. a. [Deck:] ‘A pack of cards piled regularly on each other’ (Johnson 1765); also the portion of the pack left, in some games, after the hands have been dealt.**
>
> 1594   1st Pt. Raigne Selimus sig. F4v   *If I chance but once to get the decke, To deale about and shufle as I would.*
>
> 1594   R. Barnfield Shepheard Content viii. sig. Eiij   *Pride deales the Deck whilst Chance doth choose the Card.*

The connection seems to be that the cards cover each other.

But looking at the verb which appeared later, we have:

> II. To provide with a deck; **to assemble** or pile up.
>
> **4.** Nautical. **To cover as with a deck; to furnish with a deck; to deck in, to deck over, to cover in with the deck, in ship-building.**
>
> 1624   J. Smith Gen. Hist. Virginia v. 175   *At last it was concluded, to decke their long boat with their ship hatches.*
>
> 1700   S. L. tr. C. Frick Relation Voy. in tr. C. Frick & C. Schweitzer Relation Two Voy. E.-Indies 6   *Flat Boats..tho' small, yet so close Deck't, that in a rough Sea they will go quite under the waves and retain no water.*

The sense of "assemble" is perhaps clearer in the 1700 quote.

The idea of a deck of cards thus seems to be a combination of the cards being assembled and the cards covering each other (so the players do not see them).

Comment: If I might add, cards are dealt *verdeckt*, i.e. face down. I could see the face down stack be referred to as *deck(ed)* in that sense. The similarity to *versteck-* "cover-, hid-" and En. *stack (of cards)* ~ *deck* is almost more attractive though, maybe *hous(e-s)deck/tack*. The house always wins.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of deck applied to a pack of playing cards is not clear; John Ayto, in his [Words Origin](https://books.google.it/books?id=hsRISNLSSHAC&pg=PT245&lpg=PT245&dq=corduroy%20etymology&source=bl&ots=d3y230UyCC&sig=VN0nlXm9pzSt56wZSiuuhSHU3zE&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEwIiVk7neAhUGyRoKHXQYDD44FBDoATAGegQIAhAB#v=onepage&q=Deck&f=false) suggests that

> The word’s application to a pack of cards, which dates from the 16th century, perhaps comes from the notion of the cards in a pile being on top of one another like the successive decks of a ship.

Comment: One would think that a collective noun etc for decks, had/if one existed, would have been more appropriate.